# How to use apache commons httpclient and getmethod to read a modelandview json response?

Tags: java, json, apache-commons-httpclient

Please excuse me if my formatting is off (new here). 
I have a REST service like below (implementation details omitted):

```
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView;

  @Controller
  @RequestMapping(value={"/myservice", "/myservice/"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public class MyClass{

  @RequestMapping(value={"/",""}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView doSomething(@RequestParam(value="params", required=true) String params){

    Map<String,Object> mymap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    mymap.put("myparam",params);

    return new ModelAndView(new MappingJacksonJsonView(), mymap); 
    }
  }
```

What I want to do is write a HttpClient (using org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient, I know there is another httpclient from apache out there) that can GET the "mymap" object from the above service. I understand that I have to do something like below in my client code:

```
 public Map<String,String> getMap(){

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpMethod method = new GetMethod("myurl");
 method.getParams().setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
                                  new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(3, false));

 NameValuePair [] pair = { new NameValuePair("content","mytestcontentvalue")};
 ((GetMethod)method).setQueryString(pair);

 int code = client.executeMethod(method);

 Map<String,String> mymap = ??   /// what do i do here?

 return mymap;
}
```

I have been searching for a solution but I can't find a way to read the response here. This is my FIRST time writing a client and service so may be I found a solution but never understood it :( 
Any suggestions would really help!!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the Apache HttpClient [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html):

> It is vital that the response body is always read regardless of the status returned by the server. There are three ways to do this:
>
> - Call `method.getResponseBody()`. This will return a byte array containing the data in the response body.
> - Call `method.getResponseBodyAsString()`. This will return a String containing the response body. Be warned though that the conversion from bytes to a String is done using the default encoding so this method may not be portable across all platforms.
> - Call `method.getResponseBodyAsStream()` and read the entire contents of the stream then call `stream.close()`. This method is best if it is possible for a lot of data to be received as it can be buffered to a file or processed as it is read. Be sure to always read the entirety of the data and call `close()` on the stream.

After you've retrieved the contents of the response in one of these manners, you are then free to parse the contents and get the map you are looking for... I do not believe that Apache HttpClient provides you with any more functionality for parsing than that.

You can use one of the JSON libraries for Java (see: [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)) to parse the String returned by `method.getResponseBodyAsString()`, but beware issues that may arise as the size of your response grows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I believe you can use both getResponseBody and getResponseBodyAsStream() for this.